# Apache insists on starting on boot on CentOS

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, boot

I have a CentOS server that came installed with WHM and cPanel and the corresponding LAMP stack.  I disabled Apache and MySQL and replaced them with nginx and PostgreSQL.

...Or at least I thought I did.  Apache insists on starting up on boot, blocking the ports nginx needs.  So every time the server goes down for maintenance or is restarted for some other reason, Apache starts serving an old "under construction" page we had put up.  After being alerted to the issue via a few angry phone calls, I have to shutdown Apache and start up nginx.

`chkconfig --list` httpd returns:

```
httpd           0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
```

So I don't know what's booting up Apache.  Any thoughts on what could be happening?

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you could do to fix this.

1. Track down what is pulling in httpd as a dependency and starting it.
2. Remove httpd and mysql-server packages.

Ideally, you would do both. However, if due to time constraints or based on how much you care only one of those options is likely?

[image]

If you have completely replaced Apache and MySQL then you have no reason to keep them on your system, and all they're doing is taking up space, increasing your attack surface, and increasing your risk of something untoward happening (as is going on right now).

Comment: I can't even uninstall it; `yum remove httpd` just says `No Match for argument: httpd`.

Comment: @TheronLuhn: Oh bugger me. I wonder if they bundled httpd directly in their broken install. Which might also explain your problems since the "helpful tools" are probably starting it for you. Check the output of 'rpm -qf /usr/sbin/httpd' and see what actually owns that file.

Comment: `file /usr/sbin/httpd is not owned by any package`.  Dammit.  I'll contact my host and see if they can do anything.

Comment: @TheronLuhn: Yup, this is what happens when you use things like WHM and cPanel. They break the system so it doesn't really work the way you expect it to.